# How do I setup a multi page app using vite?

Tags: javascript, html, config, vite, multi-page-application

I am trying to setup a vite project that has multiple entry points.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-swtkdv

It is a pretty basic setup taken straight from the vite website that uses vanilla flavour. Only things which I have updated are the following:

- add vite.config.js file with configuration for multiple entry points (check the attached stackblitz link)
- add new files: login/index.html; login/login.js (check the attached stackblitz link)

What I expect to happen is everytime I enter `url`/login, it should load the page `./login/index.html`. However in reality it keeps on loading the `./index.html`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct and should work exactly as they described in the docs, the problem is you typed `http://localhost:5173/login` into the browser and expected `./login/index.html` to be rendered.

In the docs they said, that with your code, in order to render `./login/index.html` you should type `http://localhost:5173/login/` into the browser. I.e. your previous URL was missing the `/` at the end.

https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app:

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you very much for the answer